# Keras backend function that gives one only if values are between a and b

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to write a Keras backend function that if the input x is between a and b, it gives 1; otherwise, it gives zero. I was not able to do this using the functions available in Keras backend.  If it was numpy, I would write:

```
def my_function(x):
    import numpy as np
    y=np.int64(np.logical_and(x>=a, x<=b))
    return y
```

**Question 1:** How can I do this using Keras backend? I know I can use something like this, but it is not efficient

```
def my_function(x):
    from keras import backend as K
    y=x
    for i in y:
        if i<=b and i>=a:
            i=1
        else:
            i=0
 return y
```

**Question 2:** I have installed TensorFlow 1.14.0 and Keras 2.2.6 so I think the backend is Tensorflow. If I cannot do it in Keras backend. How can I write my function in the TensorFlow backend?

Comment: what’s the input shape?

Comment: @zihaozhihao I have no idea. It’s the output of a layer. Can we write it for a general input shape?

Comment: Oh i see. Maybe it’s applied on logits or probs.

Comment: It will be used for neural networks

Answer (score 0):

For question 2 on TensorFlow, you can try to use TF.cond or TF.case to derive the desired output. Something like below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant(20)
y = tf.constant(22)
z = tf.constant(25)
result1 = tf.cond(tf.logical_and(x > y, x <z), lambda: tf.constant(1), lambda: tf.constant(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code I often use to resize images with opencv:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

def resize_function(image, target_height, target_width):
  img = cv2.resize(image, (target_height, target_width))
  return image.astype(np.float32)

image = tf.numpy_function(
    func=resize_function,
    inp=[tf.cast(image, tf.uint8),resize_height, resize_width],
    Tout=tf.float32)
```

tensorflow has [tf.numpy_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function) for defining your custom numpy functions.
this converts your custom functions to tensorflow graphs

if there are multiple outputs expected from a function, modify as :

```
output_1, output_2, output_3 = tf.numpy_function(
    func=compute_input_output, 
    inp=[inp_1, inp_2, inp_3,inp4], 
    Tout=[tf.float32,tf.float32,tf.float32])
```

**Tout** should contain a list of expected data-types of outputs.